# Can anyone teach me how to write the 2nd printed value into a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

### Can someone teach me how to write the 2nd printed value into a txt file.

```
while True:                              
num = int(input(""" Enter Number: """))      
temp = num                                           
numb = temp                                         
zar = 1                                             
print("Develped by Umar Mushtaq")                    
for _ in range(10):                                  
    print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)             
    num += numb
    zar+= 1
print("Press Ctrl+C To Exit")
```

Comment: what do you mean by second printed value ?

Comment: I suggest simply looking up "python3 how to write to a text file".

Answer (score 0):

You can write in a `txt` file like this:

```
f = open("filename.txt", "w")
f.write("Whatever you want to write...!!!!")
f.close()
```

This is overwrite the file. If you want to append in existing file, you can use `a` instead of `w` in parameter.

```
"a" - Append - will append to the end of the file
"w" - Write - will overwrite any existing content
```

Comment: what do you mean by 2nd printed value? If you will elaborate it then i will update my answer according to that. But if it is regarding writing in a txt file. Then, this will work. Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: I tried this but the second value  print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)  can't be written into a file because it has 5 arguments and it only takes 1 arugument.

Comment: I tried this but the second value  print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)  can't be written into a file because it has 5 arguments and it only takes 1 arugument.

Answer (score 0):

### But it gives an error :. TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (5 given)

```
with open("write.txt", "w") as f:
while True:                              
    num = int(input(""" Enter Number: """))      
    temp = num                                           
    numb = temp                                         
    zar = 1                                             
    print("Develped by Umar Mushtaq")                    
    for _ in range(10):                                  
        print(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)
        f.write(numb, "X", zar, "=", num)             
        num+= numb
        zar+= 1
print("Press Ctrl+C To Exit")
```